# Two versions of 'files' after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I recently upgraded from 17.04 to 20.04, and ended up with two versions of several programs. I googled a bit and was able to remove the old version of Atom and Chrome etc, but I have a problem with 'Files'.

[image: screenshot]

I don't know how to uninstall the older version. I can't find it using apt or snap. Any ideas?

edit:

Result of running `dpkg -l | grep nautilus`:

```
ii  libnautilus-extension1a:amd64              1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1                          amd64        libraries for nautilus components - runtime version
ii  nautilus                                   1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1                          amd64        file manager and graphical shell for GNOME
ii  nautilus-data                              1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1                          all          data files for nautilus
ii  nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal          3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04                      amd64        GNOME terminal emulator application - Nautilus extension
ii  nautilus-sendto                            3.8.6-3                                    amd64        easily send files via email from within Nautilus
ii  nautilus-share                             0.7.3-2ubuntu3                             amd64        Nautilus extension to share folder using Samba
```

Result of running  `dpkg -l | grep nemo`:

```
ii  libnemo-extension1:amd64                   4.4.2-2                                    amd64        Nemo component system facilities
ii  nemo                                       4.4.2-2                                    amd64        File manager and graphical shell for Cinnamon
ii  nemo-data                                  4.4.2-2                                    all          File manager and graphical shell for Cinnamon (data files)
ii  nemo-fileroller                            4.4.0-2                                    amd64        File Roller integration for Nemo
```

Comment: Could you edit your post adding the output of the command `dpkg -l | grep nautilus` and `dpkg -l | grep nemo`? The second icon seems the one of another file manager, just my guess. Could you also open both of them and attach the screenshot?

Comment: You mean you upgraded from 18.04 instead of 17.04? Please check and correct in your post (use "edit").

Comment: @vanadium i upgraded from 17.04 via 18.04 to 20.04 :)

Comment: You should be able to remove the one you don't want using Synaptic Package Manager. Search for Nemo and Nautilus. Ubuntu 20.04 has adopted Nemo as its default file manager see [here](https://9to5linux.com/ubuntu-unity-20-04-1-launches-with-nemo-as-default-file-manager-timeshift-backup-tool)

Comment: @Raflles, not correct for standard Ubuntu 20.04. It is the community respin with Unity where they moved to nemo.

Comment: Output says you have nemo installed. Remove it using `sudo apt remove nemo`

Comment: @vanadium Thanks for the info.